# Открытие ссылки в новой вкладке из iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужен совет или пикон в нужную сторону.

Есть сайт, crm через которую работают менеджера и smm студия которая запускает рекламу.

Дело вот в чем, формы покупки на сайте после ее заполнения отправляют(переадресует) сразу на оплату (сами эти формы сделаны(построены) через crm(getcourse) и вставляются на сайт в виде 1 скрипта который после загрузки вытягивает саму форму с crm в iframe).

SMM студия попросила поставить typage для того что бы отслеживать привлеченных ими лидов. В настройке формы нету возможности делать одновременно и переадресацию на оплату и открытие в новой вкладке typage. Есть возможность добавить js скрипт или какой-то блок в саму форму. Пробывал по клику открывать через window.onload("site","_blank") но браузер ругается на скрипт и блочить его. Нужен совет как сделать одновременно переадресацию на оплату и открытие в новой вкладке typage.

Спасибо всем кто откликнется и дочитает до конца. Если не понятно задавайте уточню как смогу.

Немного дополню.
Вид crm:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Форма вызываеться в iframe с другого домена. Браузер блочит все попытки(которые я знаю) открытие в новой вкладке ссылки работает только редирект на обработчике

Comment: а просто к ссылке добавить target="" можно ?

Comment: Нету возможности там button и на него вешается обработчик

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
if(window.name=='iframe1'){
  jQuery(window).load(function(){
     jQuery('a').attr('target','_top');
  });
}
</script>
```

Или

```html
<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/814341/edit#" target="_top">Link</a>
```

Comment: Работало бы если бы фрейм был в моем домене, но он грузит из crm(другой домен).

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте о функционале [iframe](https://habr.com/ru/articles/488516/) возможно какой-то из атрибутов даст возможность подвязатся на событие отправки

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]. возможно, лучше было оформить такое краткое сообщение как комментарий, а не ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Этот функционал можно реализовать только через систему сообщений. Фрейм посылает сообщение родителю через `parent.window.postMessage({a: 'xxx', b: 'yyy'})`, а родительское окно ловит его через `window.addEventListener("message", tractMessage, false);` и в функции tractMessage делает всё, что необходимо.